# Gnosis not signing on the contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, nft

We have sent all our contracts to the Gnosis safe which we believe would be safe for the protocol but we are having a problem.

1. We are currently trying to enable the contract to mint our NFTs but it is not carrying out the function as it should on the contract.

We received a message that reads *"transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined"*

The transaction on shown on the gnosis side that it was done but on the contract it is not showing anything.

I need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur due to RPC issues .If the transaction is confirmed on the Gnosis Safe dashboard, Check again after some time the transaction will be updated on the blockchain